# Computing density() in R for grouped frequency data

Tags: r, aggregation, kernel-density

This should be a pretty straightforward question, but I can't find the answer anywhere (in part because I'm not sure what to query for).

In R, it's easy to compute the density of:

```
c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 10, 10)
```

You just do:

```
density(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 10, 10))
```

The problem is, if I had an "ungrouped" vector like this for my data, it would be far too large for R (or the query engine that builds the dataset) to handle. So I need to use a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)` in the initial query to compress my results (as such, using `rep()` to expand the counts doesn't help). Given such a data frame of 'counts', how do I then compute the density (for a KDE plot) of a frame like:

```
Value Count
1     1
2     3
3     1
5     2
7     1
8     1
10    3
```

And just to be clear, I really do need a density plot, *not* a histogram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the weights argument

```
density(d$Value, weights=d$Count/sum(d$Count))
```

(edited to account for first comment)

Comment: I would probably set the weights as `d$Count/sum(d$Count)`, but this works very well.

Comment: Yes, without that you get a warning that it's not a true density. I edited the original post to include your suggestion.